# How do I change a particular int value in an array to a char in C?

Tags: arrays, c

How do I change an integer value in an array to a char value in C? For example: I want to change all the 0 in my array to dots. So if my array has {1, 2, 0, 0, 0, 2, 1, 0}, it should become {1, 2, ., ., ., 2, 1, .}. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `arr[2] = '.';` Note that `'.'` is a value of type `int`.

Comment: Do you want your memory to look like `{1,2,'.','.','.',2,1,'.'}` or do you want to it to look like `{'1','2','.','.','.','2','1','.'}` so you can print it?

Comment: @pmg yes, I tried that and it gives the ASCII value of 46. But I want to just put "." at every instance where there is a 0.

Comment: @Tzig I want it to look like the first one. So all the numbers are stills ints except the dots get printed instead of zeroes if I ever want to print the array. Sorry, I'm still learning C so I'm pretty new at it. Thanks!

Comment: Somewhere in your code a line similar to `int arr[n];` exists. On that exact line you said "arr is an array of ints". And now somewhere else in your code you want `arr` to be some mixed type array containing integers and characters. Mixed type arrays aren't possible in C (and don't really make sense). Instead you should change your printing function to print dots whenever it sees zeros.

Comment: All characters are just numbers.... you don't store a `'.'`... you store a number. When you use that number you can decide to  use it as a character (e.g. for printing) which means that the number is converted to a `'.'`

Comment: @StefanRiedel So I already have a printer function that basically prints in 9x9 grid (like sudokus), how can I implement it in the printer function? Like while looping through the array, if it sees array[i] = 0, it should print "."? Will this work?

Comment: @Barradism: Yes, that should work. Note that in C, the comparison operator is `==`, not `=` (which is the assignment operator).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If your array looks like this:

```c
char arr[] = {'1', '2', '0', '3', '\0'};
// or like this:
char arr[] = "1203";
```

Then you can use a loop to replace `'0'` to `'.'`:

```c
for (size_t i = 0; arr[i] != '\0'; i += 1) {
  if (arr[i] == '0') {
    arr[i] = '.';
  }
}
```

***However***, if your array looks like this:

```c
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 0, 3 };
```

Then you *cannot* replace the zeroes with a dot, because the dot is a character and not a number (there is a numerical representation of dot, i.e.: `'.'`, but it would be treated as `int` and thus not printed as a dot).

In that case, in order to print dots instead of zeroes, you must intervene in the printing function. For instance:

```c
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 0, 3 };
size_t arrlen = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); // size_t arrlen = 4;

// this code will print: 12.3 (replacing 0 with .)
for (size_t i = 0; i < arrlen; i += 1) {
  if (arr[i] == 0) {
    printf(".");
  }
  else {
    printf("%d", arr[i]);
  }
}
printf("\n");
```

Comment: Hey mate, my code is like the second one. However, when I do this: if (arr[i] == 0) {
    printf(".");
  } - it prints a dot after 0. but doesn't replace zero.

Comment: @Barradism I'm afraid you forgot to add an `else` statement like in my code.

Comment: void
sudoku_printer(int sudoku[], int num) {
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<num;i++) {
        if (sudoku[i]==0) {
            printf(".");
        }
        if (i==8 || i==17 || i==26 || i==35 || i==44 ||
            i==53 || i==62 || i==71) {
            printf("\n");
        }
        else {
            printf(" %d", sudoku[i]);
        }
    }
    printf("\n");
}

Comment: ^ That is basically my short version of my printer function as comments wont allow more characters. But I did add an else function. I still don't know how to comment in code format. Sorry for the mess. Array has a fixed 81 values given in the main function.

Comment: @Barradism You can edit your question and include the code there. Then you comment "I edited the question to include..." instead of posting the code in comments.

Comment: @Barradism You've put the `else` statement in the wrong position. You should replace `printf(" %d", sudoku[i]);` with `if (...) { printf(" ."); } else { printf(" %d" ...); }`

Comment: Oh my god yes it fixed it. Thank you so much! Life saver haha. Cheers bro!